# Form will update database on first submit, but will not update again until page is refreshed

Tags: javascript, forms, svelte

I have multiple instances of a component with a form that on submit, takes the input, hits my API, and then updates the database with the input value. Everything works as it should the first time around, database changes and the values in the component change. However if I go back to one of the instances I have already used the form on, when it's submitted, it hits the API, comes back like everything is working but nothing gets updated. After refreshing the page the cycle repeats, works the first time but second time nothing.

Tried to do some googling but everything I search for gets me nowhere and I'm not entirely certain what to search for. I don't know if this is a frontend or backend issue, using svelte for the frontend and express/sequelize for the backend.

Any ideas would be helpful or even just something to start searching for.

Thanks

Update:
This is the code for handling the submit

```js
const handleSubmit = async () => {
  let values = { 
    ot2: Number(ot2),
  };

  const config = {
    method: 'PATCH',
    headers: {
      Application: 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(values)
  }

  const submitRes = await fetch(`api\site`, config);

  if(submitRes.ok){
    const res = await fetch(`api\site`);
    const tankArr = await res.json();
    ot2 = tankArr[0].OT2;
  }
}
```

Comment: it's probably something you've done wrong with your code - there's many things you could've done that would produce this problem, so, without any code, the answer is a pineapple

Comment: You should recreate your problem in the Svelte REPL - use something like HttpBin to act as your form backend. This will allow people to understand your problem and help you.

However, 99% of the time when creating code in the REPL to demonstate problems, I find the solution to my problem :)

Comment: Are there any error messages in the console? I usually see similar behavior when there's an uncaught exception somewhere. Sounds like your code probably crashes somewhere after doing the API call, and after that nothing will work.